# CCTMXTiledMap not being added to layer

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a working tilemap that I am able to add to my 'HelloWorldLayer' with the 'addChild' method. I am trying to add several layers at time intervals by calling a class I wrote through the game timer.

I execute the following code, but I can't see the tilemap added to the layer. ('tileMapNode' is set up in my .h file).

```
    tileMapNode = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"scroller.tmx"];
    tileMapNode.anchorPoint = ccp(pos.x, pos.y);

    [layer addChild:tileMapNode]
```

the 'layer' parameter references the 'HelloWorldLayer'.

What am I doing wrong? If I add a sprite from this class to the HelloWorldLayer it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range of anchorPoint is between 0 and 1. By setting it to some position I suspect it's way out of range. Also very large tilemaps ( >16k tiles) won't render all tiles.

Comment: You're right. I was trying to set the map's position with the anchorPoint property. I fixed this by simply using the position property instead. Thanks!